# How to make asynchronous HTTP calls with asyncio python without knowing the the n

Tags: python, api, rest, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am having a hard time coming up with an approach that would implement async REST API calls on a server without knowing the amount of times (n) that I need to repeat the process beforehand.

What I mean.

I can do this now:

```
def get_tasks(session):
    tasks = []
    for i in range(1, 50):  # let's say this is the number of pages due to pagination
        tasks.append(
          session.get(url=f"{url}?page={i}", headers=header, ssl=False)
        )
    return tasks



async def query_api():
   async with aiohttp.ClientSession as session:
       tasks = get_tasks(session)
       responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
       for response in responses:
           results.append(await response.json())
```

And this works fine.

But what if I did not know beforehand the number of pages that I need to query? What if there is a variable called "next_page" in every call, and I want to use that to act as my breakpoint on when my async call will stop meaning when I will not find that object in the response any more OR I have a limit, and a skip query parameter and you just play with those and you loop until you find an empty response. Any idea how that would be done?

Comment: If you don't know how many pages, then you have to make one query to find out how many pages,. After that, your know how many pages.

Comment: so no async then? XD

Comment: You can't do two things in parallel if you don't know what the second thing is, can you? But if you can find out how many pages in the first query, then you can get all those pages in parallel after that.